# How to install android application whose assets folder size >1GB while apk max size=50 MB?

Tags: java, android, file, compression, apk

My assets Folder contain a sub-folder whose size >1 GB

I cannot install my application on ZTE device whose sd Card size =8 GB

I add `write/read permission` to my manifest file and also `preferExternal installation`

After some search in related question I see that maximum apk size is 50 MB

So I should reduce my application ressource file

and I read that I can install my application without ressource and then donwnolad them in the

first use

Any one can explain more this idea or suggest another idea

I don't know if it is possible that I use big text files in android application

Answer (score 2):

Correct, APKs have a maximum file-size of 50MB. To extend your app beyond the 50MB limit you can use one or two expansion files, each file being max 2GB. [Refer to the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) for details regarding this.

I would also ask myself if all of these assets are needed to use the application. The app would have to be pretty damn good/provide a lot of value before I'd download 1GB of data. Perhaps you could server up chunks of data from a server and download to external storage?

Comment: I'ma still in developing stage and  all those data are required.How caan I server up chunks of data ?

Comment: The solution you provided is useful in case of installing app from Google play but I am still in developping stage

Comment: The documentation recommends and describes how you can perform testing of expansion files before release: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data for developing purposes; you can load the data on the external sd card of your test android device(i.e. the device you'r testing the app on). You can acess these files through code:

`File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/assets"+...);`

root will now hold the root directory of the sd card; dir will get you the Directory to whatever files you'd want to access. You can read/write these files using standard java File and FileReader Objects. This should work for development purposes. And yeah; dont forget to add the required permission in your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

However; frankly it won't be a good idea to ask the user of an app to download one gigabyte worth of data for your app to run. Instead it will be better to host these files on an external server and access them indirectly from android through the internet; every time the app runs.
There are a few ways to do this. If its simple text stored in databases, you can use php to send it as JSON encoded strings; but since its >1GB of data i'm assuming it's probably images/videos and not plain text. Here is a simple tutorial that helps you to download an image from a URL: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/ You can try looking into this further

Comment: I exactly do what u say in the first part of your answer, my data is a plain text=is an svm model (machine learning) with a special format that I can't stored it in databases.The external server it is may be my pc (I'am still in developing stage)?

Comment: hey sorry but i did not fully understand... if you are still in the developing stage, you can store the raw data in the sd card and access it... there is no need to store it in the database for now.
As for later; you can put these files up for download; http://blog.cuelogic.co.in/android-code-to-upload-download-large-files-to-server/